# Java Scanner next(".") give me java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm testing java scanner with:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("hello");
String k = s.next(".");             // <<<<-----this line throws exception
System.out.println(k);
```

even with Pattern gives me the same exception.
Am I missing something?
thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the doc states for [`Scanner.next(Pattern str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next-java.util.regex.Pattern-) : *Returns the next token if it matches the specified pattern*,

So if you want to get something in `k` you need a pattern that match `hello` like

- `.*`  : zero to infinite thing

  ```
  s.next(".*");
  ```
- `\\w+` one to infinite  word-char

  ```
  s.next("\\w+");
  ```

---

*Notice :*

- You code `s.next(".");` looks for any struff but only once, your string doesn't match
- This code will read first word only as the default delimiter is `space`

  ```
  Scanner s = new Scanner("hello foo");
  System.out.println(s.next(".*"));      // hello
  ```
- so this code will read codz entirely as there is no `-` char

  ```
  Scanner s = new Scanner("hello foo");
  s.useDelimiter("-");
  System.out.println(s.next(".*"));      // hello foo
  ```

Comment: but then, `s.next(".*");` is basically just the same as `s.next()`, isn't it?

Comment: @Hulk , got uhh , `.* `is just a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern matches any token that is exactly one char. For example

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("h e l l o");
String pattern = ".";
while (s.hasNext(pattern))
    System.out.println(s.next(pattern));
```

will output

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

but if the first token does not match, such as in `"he l l o"`, this won't print anything. You'd have to consume the non-matching token in some other way.
If you actually want to redefine what the delimiter between 2 tokens should be, use [`useDelimiter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#delimiter()) instead.

Comment: `String pattern = ".*";` is more apt, isn't it??  :)

Comment: So to read only one char should i use another method....I thought I could read something like sum(39,mul(3,45)) with s.nextInt and then s.next(".") . Do I have to use findInLine(".")

Comment: @sefiroths well, if the comma "," is always a delimiter and cannot also appear as, for example, a decimal or grouping separator, then you could just try `Scanner s = new Scanner("sum(39,mul(3,45))").useDelimiter("[(,)]");` to get the tokens `[sum, 39, mul, 3, 45]` from `hasNext()`. If the comma can have other meanings too, you'll have to use an approach that takes context into account. If eg. the following might appear as input: `println("$ 1,000,000.00");`, the String would be split into multiple tokens - you usually don't want that.